# How can I make an anchor tag fill an li element when there is a p element right underneath the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to make an anchor tag fill the contents of the li element. I have already searched the forums and only found examples of only anchor tags within the li. I feel as if my CSS is correct, but there is a p element that is also within the li element. So my anchor tag is sharing the space with my paragraph element.

HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="search-results">
   <ul id="output">
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#output li a {
  display: flex;
  color: #D0CCD0;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px black solid;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#output').append("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" + data[1][i] +
      "</a><p>" + data[2][i] +"</li>");
```

I have the codepen project so you can test it out here: https://codepen.io/rembrandtreyes/pen/OjpVyw

Comment: If the a element fills the li element, the p element must overflow the li element. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: I think you have forgot to mention that what is your  question.

Comment: I do not want it to overflow. I need the p and a element to stay within the li element

Comment: Why not build your HTML this way? `<li><a href="#"><p>some text</p></a></li>`

Comment: @shemaya I tried it that way and what ends up happening is I have two block elements sitting inside the li element. None of which fill the li element completely.

Comment: @RembrandtReyes maybe this is what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/xzqumhx1/ You just need to set the anchor to display block

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from display:flex

Comment: I have tried flex, inline-block and block none of which fill the height of the li element.

Answer (score 0):

html tag has default display property to 'block' and you have set display of anchor (a) to flex. That's why its overflowing. Change both to

```
p,a{
       display:inline;
   }
```

or give them class if you wants to change only few p and a tags